# How to edit relative path in css file with npm scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app`. After running `npm run build` there is one build folder is generating. Under this folder there is one minified css file. I want to edit this file, when i'm running `npm run build`. 
Instead of

```
url(/static/media/fontawesome-webfont.674f50d2.eot)
```

I want it should be like

```
url(../media/fontawesome-webfont.674f50d2.eot)
```

How to do this with npm scripts.

Answer (score 0):

With create-react-app you can modify the final path of your compiled scripts by changing the value of homepage in **package.json** but unfortunally at this moment with the lastest version of create-react-app (1.0.11) you only can modify the path **before** the /static/ with the homepage property

So if you modify the homepage property to look like this "../" the final path will be `url(../static/media/fontawesome-webfont.674f50d2.eot)`